# Getting the data from a button when it is clicked and inserting this into a query in another pages C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7, button

I'm looking to get 4 buttons which all lead to the same page. But depending on which button was chosen the contents of a query in that destination page is different.

So for example lets say that the buttons are named "button1" "button2" "button3" and "button4". These buttons are located on a page called TitlePage.xaml.

Then all the buttons navigate to a page called MainPage.xaml and within the code of this page is this piece of code

`var qry = "/tblChemicals?$filter = " + (here is where i want to reference the button clicked) +" eq '" + Search.Text +"'";`

So if button one was clicked the string would actuall read

`var qry = "/tblChemicals?$filter = button1 eq '" + Search.Text +"'";`

Here is the XAML code where the buttons are defined

```
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Button1" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="143,6,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="Button2" Content="Button2" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="143,6,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="Button3" Content="Button3" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="143,6,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="Button4" Content="Button4" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="143,6,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is creating a event in TitlePage.xaml.cs
    and subscribe to it in Main.xaml.cs.
    Then raise the event in the button
    clicked event handler.

Details can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I would say your almost there..

```
 var qry = "/tblChemicals.xaml?$filter = " + (here is where i want to reference the button clicked) +" eq '" + Search.Text +"'"; 
 // Now you can do something like this
 NavigationService.Navigate(qry);
```

In your page you need to read the querystring back. (There's probably a better way to do this... but here's some sloppy code from one of my apps "OnNavigatedTo" event:

```
 var qry = NavigationService.CurrentSource.ToString().Split('?')[1];
```

That's it. Be sure to mark me as the answer if you think I have resolved your problem.